# Session Storage data goes away after redirecting and coming back from another domain

Tags: javascript, redirect, browser, session-storage

In my website, I am using session storage to store some data. Now in a use case, a user gets redirected to another website to complete the transaction and is again redirected back to my website. Sometimes I do not see the session storage variable I saved before the user was redirected to another website. I am seeing this issue across all browsers - Chrome, Safari, Mozilla.
Can anyone suggest if this is a known issue with session storage or I am missing something here?

Comment: Share your snippets

Comment: When you navigate to different origin , browser will treat as a different session , thats why your session storage is getting cleared

Comment: @SarthakGupta I think you're wrong about that. I saved something in my `sessionStorage`, and then entered my website: `localhost:3000` then edited url in the address bar to `google.com`. Now I went back to `localhost:3000` and I had my data there.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible that there is some bug in the browser. Recently, I found a regression in Chrome for macOS that caused a similar issue where session storage was lost during redirects.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1500397

Answer (score -3):

That's the point of `sessionStorage`: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

You probably wanna use `localStorage` and clean it manually when not needed anymore

Comment: The docs does not mention anything about session ending if user stays in same tab

Comment: No, but you said "a user gets redirected to another website to complete the transaction and is again redirected back to my website", so when you leave the tab the session storage gets cleared

Comment: User does not leave the tab, he is redirected in the same tab and comes back in the same tab only